# How to turn off dinghy-http-proxy when Dinghy VM starts

Tags: docker, dinghy

I use [Dinghy](https://github.com/codekitchen/dinghy) virtual machine as docker development environment.

When I start dinghy VM (`dinghy up`) - dinghy-http-proxy container is started also.

How I can turn off it by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit-1**

Seems like the code for dinghy always loads the container at start. You can manually fix it for now

Open `/usr/local/Cellar/dinghy/4.5.0/cli/cli.rb`. The `4.5.0` will change based on the version you have

Near line 227 you will find

```
http_proxy.up(expose_proxy: !!proxy)
```

You need to comment this line. Then destroy and recreate the VM

```
dinghy destroy
dinghy create
```

You can also open a request on github to ask author to give such an option. There does exist a config file at `cat ~/.dinghy/preferences.yml`

```
---
:preferences:
  :proxy_disabled: true
  :fsevents_disabled: false
  :dns_disabled: true
  :dns: false
  :create:
    provider: virtualbox
```

But i tried all options and they don't work. So final resolution was to comment the line which brings up the container without any condition.

**Original Answer**

This will only stop the container after the VM has been started, if you restart or halt then next time the proxy will be started again

You need to use below

```
$ dhingy ssh

$ docker update --restart no dinghy-http-proxy
$ docker stop dinghy-http-proxy
```

Assuming the container is named `dinghy-http-proxy` if it has an id then you would need to find that using `docker ps`

Comment: @DmitryRomashov, please check the updated answer now

Comment: I turned off `dns` and `proxy_disabled` preferences and dinghy-http-proxy container won't start again after `dinghy up` command.